# Хеш-таблица (Hashtable) на языке C#. Для чего она?

Tags: c#, структуры-данных

Изучаю теорию, подскажите, какое практическое применение Hashtable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хеш таблица (`Hashtable`) VS словарь (`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`).

Что общего:

1. Оба работают как хранилище ключ-значение
2. Оба обеспечивают (псевдо)константный доступ к значению по ключу
3. Оба хранят данные в массиве корзин (расходы по памяти у обоих в линейной зависимости от количества элементов)

В чем разница:

1. Таблица приводит ключи и значения к `object`, что добавляет расходов по памяти и скорости (на boxing/unboxing)
2. Таблица, в отличии от словаря, поддерживает многопоточное чтение / однопоточную запись. Словарь же не рассчитан на несколько одновременных читателей / одного писателя (я однажды на этом запорол релиз, будьте аккуратней)
3. У таблицы есть [враппер](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,1143) для получения потокобезопасной таблицы. У словаря я такого не увидел.
4. Таблица и словарь по разному обсчитывают коллизии. Таблица пользуется [двойным хешированием](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing), словарь хранит что то типа указателя на следующий элемент прямо в корзине (не знаю как этот метод называется). По идее (по моему мнению) из за этого словарь должен обрабатывать коллизии на чтение чууть быстрее, но я не проверял.

Comment: А что есть коллизии?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch [коллизия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) - это когда разные ключи имеют одинаковый хеш

Comment: А если хеш одинаковые не-значит ли это что объекты одинаковые?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch нет, не значит. Вот если хеши разные - то объекты точно разные (если хеш функция корректно написана). Но если хеши одинаковые, то либо объекты одинаковые, либо это коллизия хеш функции

Comment: Есть потокобезопасный вариант словаря - ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: @ВладимирШ. я в курсе, но потокобезопастный словарь выходит за рамки вопроса и ответа, это вообще отдельная песня со своими приколами

Answer (score 6):

По сути `Hashtable` — это нетипизированная версия словаря (`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) и ее можно использовать в тех же ситуациях, когда вы использовали бы словарь.

Но в современных реалиях это очень редко требуется и лучше отдать предпочтение именно строготипизированной структуре данных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вот и я думаю какой смысл в этом вопросе на собеседовании, А в плане производительности что лучше, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> или хештабл.

Comment: Тут, в первую очередь, надо понимать, что при использовании нетипизированной коллекции все ValueType будут подвергаться упаковке (boxing), поэтому Hashtable с их использованием будет отставать в производительности. Но сами алгоритмы и способы хранения внутри `Dictionary` и `Hashtable` должны быть аналогичными (в исходники не ходил — можете сделать это сами, если интересно), поэтому, с точки зрения асимптотики операций на них, они одинаковы.

Comment: В общем, `Hashtable` — это исторический артефакт, который появился, когда еще не было дженериков (т. е. до C# 2)

Comment: А какой смысл в реализации собственной хештаблицы, такой вопрос видел на собеседовании?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Давайте так, классы `Hashtable` и `Dictionary` — и тот и тот являются одинаковыми, с точки зрения алгоритмов и структур данных, реализациями хеш-таблицы в BCL (стандартная библиотека классов .NET). И если вы пишете какой-то вычислительный алгоритм, эта реализация хеш-таблицы вполне может вас не устроить и вы можете написать свою реализацию, которая будет более производительной в конкретной задаче.